# How can I move a div element to the bottom of the screen?

Tags: html

I am making a html file (that is just for me, and for having fun coding) and I need a div element (with other elements inside of it) to be at the bottom of my screen, but not move despite being pushed by another element's margin. I kind of drag the player section element to the bottom by using `margin-bottom:-100px`. These are the only two elements in my document right now (not counting the ones inside the div). When I run the code, the player section div doesn't move at all.

```css
#output{
    border:solid 2px #234;
    background-color:#234;
    border-radius:10%;
    max-height:100px;
    height:auto;
    padding:5px;
}
#player-section{
    margin-bottom:-100px;
}
```

This is what I have so far. I use the -100px to move the player section to the bottom but for some reason it does not work.

Comment: can you please edit question and post code you tried ?

Comment: Okay, however, my question changed (but its still related to what I am trying to do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try like

```
#output{
    border:solid 2px #234;
    background-color:#234;
    border-radius:10%;
    max-height:100px;
    height:auto;
    padding:5px;
    overflow : auto;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: This worked, But I was trying to move the player section to the bottom. I adjusted it for that, and it worked. Thank you so much!